# Refresh current page in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is there any way to refresh page in every 10 seconds using SvelteKit?
I have to refresh page to get output from endpoint.

Loading data in `src/routes/[id].svelte` from `src/routes/[id].ts`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I called setInterval(/* fetching code */) inside of onMount

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

To refresh an endpoint you can use invalidate in your page route.

```
import { onDestroy } from "svelte";
import { invalidate } from "$app/navigation";

export your_end_point_prop;

// resfresh your_end_point_prop
const apiInterval = setInterval(async () => {
  await invalidate("/your_endpoint");
}, 1000000); 

... code to handle your end_point_prop

onDestroy(() => {
    clearInterval(apiInterval);
});
```